# SSL_ctx_add_session giving segmentation fault while running on a 2 core system but not on a 4 core system?

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

I have an application that uses OpenSSL. I assign only one SSL_CTX object(not per core) and my application is multi-threaded. When my connection count reaches above 20000 I get a segementation fault. This is the trace from gdb:

```
#0  0x00007ffff61e342f in SSL_SESSION_list_remove (ctx=0x555555e1ac80, s=0x0) at ssl/ssl_sess.c:1138
#1  0x00007ffff61e2738 in remove_session_lock (ctx=0x555555e1ac80, c=0x7fffd4257220, lck=0) at ssl/ssl_sess.c:758
#2  0x00007ffff61e25f5 in SSL_CTX_add_session (ctx=0x555555e1ac80, c=0x7fffe00a1cf0) at ssl/ssl_sess.c:731
#3  0x00007ffff61d9c5b in ssl_update_cache (s=0x7fffe0255000, mode=2) at ssl/ssl_lib.c:3411
#4  0x00007ffff62031b8 in tls_finish_handshake (s=0x7fffe0255000, wst=WORK_MORE_A, clearbufs=1, stop=1)
    at ssl/statem/statem_lib.c:1072
```

As you can see value of s is NULL.So after checking out the code for Openssl I found out that its default size for cache is 20480 sessions and after that Openssl tries to remove sessions from the session queue using the function remove_session_lock which then calls SSL_SESSION_list_remove. So this process of removal of sessions does not bring a segmentation fault for me when I run my application on a 4 core system. So my question is : Where are the sessions stored and are they local to a core or are they local to a SSL_CTX object? 
And why does a 4 core system does not give a segmentation fault?

Comment: This is likely a race condition and these usually do happen only in specific circumstances. Your 2 core systems seems more likely to trigger the race with your specific program and usage pattern than your 4 core system. Unless you can provide some actual and minimal code to reproduce the problem one cannot help you - just based on the stack trace is impossible. In general be very careful when using openssl with threads - see also https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2017/02/21/threads/.

Comment: Lets say I allocate SSL_CTX object to core 0. Now I have two threads one running on core 0 while other on core 1. Now both of them can add and remove sessions that are stored by ctx object on core 0. So, the probability of a race condition should be less in 2 core system rather than a 4 core system because I have less number of threads.. Am I right in assuming this?

Comment: First, it is not even clear that what you see as crash is really the source and not a side effect of some other memory corruption on some other place. Then, you don't likely run only the critical code in a loop on all cores, instead a specific usage pattern of your application happens on 2 core and another on 4 core - this might the difference how likely it is to crash. It might be for example that on 4 core it gets less often rescheduled to a different thread inside critical sections since more cores are available for running.